# Argument of type is not assignable to parameter of type when using useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following TypeScript error when using useState `Argument of type '(previousState: IsProducts) => { list: IsProduct[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IsProducts'.`

I'm not too sure what the issue is with the type. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated :)

```
export interface IsProduct {
    name: string;
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
}

export interface IsProducts {
    list: IsProduct[];
}

const [products, setProducts] = useState<IsProducts | undefined>({
        list: [
            {
                name: 'Test One',
                price: 20,
                quantity: 2,
            },
            {
                name: 'Test Two',
                price: 10,
                quantity: 1,
            },
        ],
    });

setProducts((previousState: IsProducts) => {
                return {
                    ...previousState,
                    list: previousState.list.map((product: IsProduct, idx: number) => {
                        if (idx === index) {
                            return {
                                ...product,
                                quantity: product.quantity >= 10 ? (product.quantity = 10) : product.quantity + 1,
                            };
                        }
                        return product;
                    }),
                };
            });
```

Removing `setProducts` from `IsProductContext` removes the above error, but throws a different error on context.

```
export interface IsProductContext {
    products: IsProducts;
    setProducts: (products: IsProducts) => void;
}
```

Comment: Could you include your initialisation of `setProducts` (i.e. the `useState` usage)?

Comment: I have updated the above to include the `useState`.

Comment: That's passing validation fine for me [in this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-resonance-tklzwq?file=/src/App.tsx) ... That error you're getting suggests that `setProducts` is not a raw "setter" as returned by `useState`. Might help if you could provide a [fully-contained example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Im using React Context and just noticed if I remove `setProducts` from the context type, the initial error goes away, but throws a different one for the context. Updated the above.

Comment: Property 'setProducts' does not exist on type 'IsProductContext'.ts(2339)

Comment: Obviously if you remove `setProducts` from the context then it will complain about it not being there when you try to access it :-)

Comment: There's no problem with providing `setProducts` through the context, but your definition in the context type only specifies that it can be called directly with `IsProducts`, rather than using the callback form. You could specify `setProducts: (products: IsProducts | ((old: IsProducts | undefined) => IsProducts)) => void`

Comment: The following did the trick 
`
export interface IsProductContext {
    products: IsProducts;
    setProducts: (products: IsProducts | ((previousState: IsProducts) => IsProducts)) => void;
}
` Thanks for help on this.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke useState you parametrized it with IsProducts | undefined, and then when you call setProducts you have previousState: IsProducts. You have mismatch types.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75920284/argument-of-type-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-when-using-usestate#comment133909967_75920284). You create `setProducts` with `useState`:

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState<IsProducts | undefined>(...);
```

At this point, `setProducts` has this somewhat opaque and unhelpful type:

```js
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IsProducts | undefined>>
```

Inspecting the React typings you can confirm that these are aliases for more familiar constructs:

```js
type Dispatch<A> = (value: A) => void;

type SetStateAction<S> = ((prevState: S) => S) | S;
```

No surprises – we can call `setProducts(..)` either with an `IsProducts | undefined` value, or a function that returns an `IsProducts | undefined` value.

Your context type is:

```js
export interface IsProductContext {
    products: IsProducts;
    setProducts: (products: IsProducts) => void;
}
```

`setProducts` in the context has a different type from `setProducts` as returned by `useState` – `context.setProducts` only advertises that it accepts an `IsProducts` value, not the callback form. When you supply it with a callback value, Typescript rightly reports an error.

If you update the context type to match React's typings for the setter returned by `useState` ...

```js
export interface IsProductContext {
    products: IsProducts;
    setProducts: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IsProducts | undefined>>;
}
```

... then you're all good.

As a side-note, in my projects I generally set up a couple of aliases for these type of state update functions, to decouple them from React more than anything else:

```js
type StateSetter<T> = (update: StateUpdate<T>) => void;
type StateUpdate<T> = T | ((prevT: T) => T);
```

in which case you would have `setProducts: StateSetter<IsProducts | undefined>` in your context.